# Why is the inconsistency of data sent by my node.js code and Postman tool?

Tags: node.js, http-post

I have following node.js code to make a HTTP request:

```
var data = {
    'Token' : 'cfe45090d19da5dbcc41a1f48c8cfd030e2af9d9',
    'BrandId' : 2,
    'Data': [{   /* one entry */
        'Email': 'test@test.com',
        'Name': 'test',
        'Cphone': '5553338888',
    }],
}

var formData = JSON.stringify(data)
var contentLength = formData.length

var headers = {
    'Content-Length': contentLength,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

var req_options = {
    uri: 'https://webAPI',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: formData,
}

request(req_options, function (error, response, body) {
    // response handling
)}
```

The HTTP post request is made successfully. I can get the server response with code 200. However, the server thinks my data is wrong (proprietary protocol).

So I test it with a HTTP request tool (Chrome extension - Postman), and here is the screen shot for the data I sent:

[image]
The server does reply that my data is right. (proprietary protocol)

What is wrong with the above code that would cause this inconsistency? (between the data I sent by the code and the data sent by Postman tool)

EDIT:

I want to modify the node.js code so that it can achieve what is done in Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node, you are encoding the data as JSON.

In Postman, it is encoding the data as form data.

You can make the reuqest in node by using this:

```
request({
    uri: 'https://webAPI',
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        Token: 'cfe45090d19da5dbcc41a1f48c8cfd030e2af9d9',
        BrandId: '2',
        Data: JSON.stringify([{   /* one entry */
            Email: 'test@test.com',
            Name: 'test',
            Cphone: '5553338888',
       }])
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't want to switch over to JSON in postman. I want to switch node.js code to what is done in postman.